# Redefining Plus and Times in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to work with sparse arrays in Mathematica
like: a=SparseArray[{},{m,n},"*"]
with default value * instead of zero. Is it
possible to extend Plus and Times in such a way
that:

Plus[1,*]=*
Times[1,*]=*
but
Plus[0,*]=0

Thanks,
Lavoslav

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking here for advice on how to modify intrinsic functions, I conclude that you are not yet an experienced enough user of Mathematica for you safely to make such modifications.

Yes, it is possible to modify the definitions and activities of Mathematica's intrinsic functions such as `Plus` and `Times`. But it is almost certainly a **very bad idea**. The chief threat is that, and this applies particularly with such fundamental operations as addition and multiplication, it is very difficult to control the impact of such modifications to only those situations where you want, and understand, the impact.

A much better idea would be to define your own versions of the functions to operate as you wish.  Such an operation might start like this;

`mySparseArrayPlus[term1_SparseArray,term2_] :=`

I think also that you should avoid the use of a string such as `"*"` for the default value in your `SparseArray`s, instead use a `Symbol`.

If you must tinker with `Plus` and `Times` approach it through the definition of `UpValues`; [this page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AssociatingDefinitionsWithDifferentSymbols.html) from the Mathematica documentation provides a good place to start your reading.

Finally, if you must interfere, read all about `Unprotect`.  Good luck and don't come back asking for help when you break addition and multiplication.

Comment: Yes, I am the very beginner :)) Thanks for advice.
L.